# Difference between '|' and '+' in bit manipulation

Tags: bit-manipulation

I want to use

`00`, `01`, `10`, `11` to represent

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

Assuming that I have a string, I want to express all substrings whose length is 5. So that I can express

> `AAABB` as `0000000101`.

Now, I have a string **s** and an integer **mark** which is used to represent substring of **s**. When I add a B into the substring **mark = mark<<2 | 1**
My question is what's the difference between **mark = mark<<2 | 1** and **mark = mark<<2 + 1**

Answer (score 1):

Might depend on the language you are using (please add a tag next time!), but typically the operator precedence will be: + << |

So you are actually comparing `(mark << 2) | 1` and `mark << (2+1)`. Expect totally different results.

If your question is about `|` (bitwise OR) and `+` (addition), then I encourage you to learn what each operator does, and come back with a more specific question.

In case you are wondering: `(mark << 2) | 1` and `(mark << 2) + 1` return the same result, because the left-shift guarantees the last bit to be zero.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The different result is caused by precedence. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned that it depends on the programming language or tool you are using and how they treat + as.

`+` is usually mostly used as addition, so if it's a binary addition, results can be very different. For example, (assume 8 bit number),

`01011001 + 000000001 => 01011010`

where as,

```
01011001 | 00000001 => 01011001
```